# Internal link with tooltip

Tags: acronyms, acrobat, pdfcomment

How can I combine the `acronym` package with the `pdfcomment` package?

I want that a tool tip will aprear on hovering to a acronym link. How can I combine that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\section{Content}
I'm using a \ac{PKI}... A \pdftooltip{special}{With a tool tip!} word.

And here comes something about \pdftooltip{\acp{CA}}{\aclp{CA}}, but this don't work.

\section{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{PKI}{Public Key Infrastructure}
  \acro{CA}{Certificate Authority}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the pdf hyperlink to the acronym list overlies the tooltip. So you can't see the tooltip message of the acronym but of the hyperlink (i.e. Page #1). If you use the `nohyperlinks` option of the acronym package the pdf hyperlinks will be switched off and you will see the tooltip message of the acronym.