# Is it possible to add a tooltip to a PDF link?

Tags: hyperref, tooltips

If I send an HTML file to someone by email, they can always be a little prudent and hover over a link before clicking. A tooltip shows them the destination URL, and this gives them a chance to know where the link will take them before actually clicking.

When I send a PDF file, the link remains burried. A recipient has no way of evaluating whether they are already familiar with the destination before going there, whether they are interested, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\huge\href{http://google.com}{Google} it or
\href{http://bing.com}{Bing} it.

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to add a tooltip to a PDF link? A solution that works on just Acrobat Reader is a good start. One that also works on OS X Preview is better.

Related discussions: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155518/9549), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42504/9549)

Comment: Is this issue still open or have you solved it? How?

Comment: @Mensch It's wide open. Any hints?

Comment: Can you please actualize your infos in your question: Which TeX distribution in which version with which OS are you using?

Comment: @Mensch With TeX Live 2017 on macOS (High Sierra) the problem is partially fixed. Preview shows a tooltip. Adobe Digital Editions (is that the sequel to Adobe Reader?) doesn't show a tooltip.

Comment: Well, the culprit here is that you can never be sure, that the pdf viewer another reader uses is able to view the tooltip. You do not know which pdf viewer is used and only a few of them can display tooltip. The reason of that is burried in the used viewer you can not change or force to view tooltip. For example if javascript of java is used in the viewer to display them, they can not work on my system, because for security reasons I deactivated them. See also this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160806/16550. So is it really worth the work to implement it in your latex code?