# Howto translate "Goto page N" tooltip in PDF Viewer for cite related links

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I'm using PDFLaTeX, biblatex and the hyperref package. I'm viewing the PDF file with the PDF viewer coming with TeXWorks, and the tooltip (or hover text) for the citation links is saying "Goto page N" while everything else is translate to Norwegian (Bokmål). For example in the bibliography, the back link text is "se side N" (and not "see page N").

I have searched the source code of various packages without find the offending string. It might be insert by PDFTeX itself and maybe hyperref is the package to blame ... Any help - real solutions or work-arounds are appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean a tooltip shown by the PDF viewer? If yes, I guess it depends on the language settings of the viewer and can’t be changes by TeX …

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you refer to (an MWE along with a screen shot could help), but Tobi is probably right that your PDF reader recognised a link and added the tool tip itself. LaTeX has no word to say in that regard.

Comment: I'm aware of the usefulness of MWEs. but in this case I didn't find it worth the work. Posting a screen shot would have helped I guess. @Tobi, you were spot on - it's the link tooltip from the PDF viewer I'm talking about. If the tooltip can't be changed through hyperref feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

It has been a while since I have used LaTeX. I have mostly coded web sites/apps lately where the tooltip/hover text can be changed through the alt and/or title attribute of the link. I expected the same from LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this tooltip is automatically added by the PDF viewer and can’t be changed from within TeX or with any PDF independent from the creating software.

However here are some related posts:

- [Override default cite tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126908/4918)
- [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155518/4918)
- [Internal link with tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42504/4918)